# Problems with saving and restoring data

Tags: android, file, save, restore

I am saving a couple of things when I exit an Activity.
First in an object and the second is an int value.

It saves ok but when I try to read back I get an EOFException when trying to get the second item.

```
    private void saveData(){
        FileOutputStream saveFile = null;
        try {
            saveFile = this.openFileOutput(STATE_SAVE_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);
            output.writeObject(game); 
            output.write(ScoringForScoreloop.getScore());
            output.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally {
                try {
                    saveFile.close();
                } 
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } 
        }

    } 

private void restoreData(){
        FileInputStream restoreFile = null;
        try {
                try {
                    restoreFile = this.openFileInput(STATE_SAVE_FILE_NAME);
                } 
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    inGame = false;
                    return;     // If no file then ok - we will start a new game
                }

                ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(restoreFile);
                game = (GameControl) input.readObject();
                ScoringForScoreloop.setScore(input.readInt());
                inGame = (game!=null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            inGame = false;
            return;     // If error then we will start a new game
        }
        finally {
                try {
                    restoreFile.close();
                    this.deleteFile(STATE_SAVE_FILE_NAME);   // delete it so we don't restore from it again
                } 
                catch (Exception   ex) {
                    inGame = false;
                    return;     // If error then we will start a new game
                }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used these classes in Java before, but I'll hazard a guess.  I suspect the problem is a difference between int and Integer in Java.

In the write code, have you tried replacing

```
output.write(ScoringForScoreloop.getScore());
```

with

```
output.writeInt(ScoringForScoreloop.getScore());
```

That way you should be symmetrical on read and write in terms of type handling.